# How to identify which particles can run in the loop for Higgs decays to gluons and photons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, higgs

I am following the lecture notes given in "[Higgs physics within and beyond the Standard Model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1786)" by HE. Logan and on pages 21 to 24 she discusses Higgs boson decays to photons and gluons which occur at one loop. For equation 97:

$$
\Gamma(h \rightarrow \gamma \gamma)=\frac{\alpha^{2}}{256 \pi^{3}} \frac{m_{h}^{3}}{v^{2}}\left|\sum_{i} N_{c i} Q_{i}^{2} F_{i}\left(\tau_{i}\right)\right|^{2}
$$

she says "the sum runs over all particles that can run in the loop". My question is, how do we determine which particles can run in the loop?

Comment: What charged particles do you know of that the Higgs can resolved to? She told you on p 21, and  eqns (97,98,99)! presumably you have understood the SM.

Comment: Hypothetically, is it not all the charged particles in the SM with energies great enough to produce the gluons? Though of course the width would be very small for some particles depending on their mass?

Comment: Hypothetically all charged particles are in the loop. Gluons? Your rate has photons. The particles in the loop have propagators peaking at their mass, so it is a complex tradeoff. She gives you the answer of what dominates where (and you should be able to understand the *why* ).

Comment: Sorry I meant photons. For gluons she says it is only quarks, which makes sense because they are the only particle which couple to both gluons and the Higgs as the quarks are the only (except gluons) particles carrying color, right? Is my above comment correct, replacing "gluons" for "photons"?

Comment: Yes. How can I tell you something she does not say, quite clearly? What ***is*** the hangup? Do you appreciate Feynman diagrams?